# how to disable scrollover top in uitableview , ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm new to iOS. I want to disable scrollovertop in `UITableView`. I did try `[self.table setBounce:NO]`, but my table's scrolloverbottom was disabled as well. I just want to disable scrollovertop. Please help me out.

Comment: what do you mean by scroll top

Comment: "over" scroll when I pull down the first item in my table .

Comment: You can stop horizontal or vertical scrolling stop only i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
    {
        CGPoint point = [scrollView contentOffset];
        if (point.y < 0) 
        {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add `UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: Happy New Year to you too !! :)